# If "yet" means "and despite that", then what word means "and partially owing to that"?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

> The child is only 4 years old, yet it can already talk.
>
> The child is only 4 years old, and, despite this, it can already talk.
>
> The child is only 4 years old, and, at least partially owing to its young age, doesn't have such great balance.

How do I make the last sentence more concise?

As a sidenote, is it not correct to refer to the subject *"child"* as *"it"*?

Comment: How about *due to* and *due, in part, to*

Comment: How does "despite that" work in the sentence about a four-year-old talking? The child isn't talking despite his age.

Comment: old Q, but to answer the side Q: referring to a child as "it" is not grammatically incorrect, but is offensive to many. use "he" or "she" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be parallel to *"The child is only 4 years old, **yet** it can already talk,"* I would like to suggest ***naturally*** as a hint that at least the consequence is partially owing to the mentioned fact. Thus, for your example,

> *The child is only 4 years old, **naturally** it doesn't have such great balance.*

If the consequence is definitive or certain, the words ***thus***, ***hence***, and ***so***, could be used.

To tone the certainty down a little, words such as ***inevitably***, ***unavoidably***, and ***naturally*** are more appropriate.

Comment: +1 for 'so', which I think is the simplest for casual, day-to-day usage — *The child is only four years old, so doesn't have such great balance.*. I don't know if I'd agree that 'inevitably' or 'unavoidably' reduces certainty though :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Jim has stated in a comment, the best way that I can think of to reduce the third sentence is to say

> The child is only 4 years old, and, due to their young age, doesn't have such great balance.

In this case "due" would be taken to mean that age is the only or the major factor in regards to the child's balance.

Combining "due" with "in part" would lead to the following sentence:

> The child is only 4 years old, and, due in part to their young age, doesn't have such great balance

This would imply that age is one of the reasons for the lack of balance, but may not be the major source of the balance issue. I would prefer this sentence in the case that I was discussing the child and specifically wanted to link their age to their lack of balance, even if something else (bad hand eye co-ordination, some kind of disorder etc.) is more related as a reason.

In regards to your other question, English uses "they" instead of "it" in sentences where you are unsure whether the child is male or female. Calling a child "it" is usually taken as you regarding the child as an object rather than a person, which would likely offend a number of people (of course, people are more forgiving if you are a foreign speaker). I would change the related sentence to read the following, unless you knew the specific gender (in which case "he" or "she" would work)

> The child is only 4 years old, yet they can already talk.

As a third side note, the second and third sentences should not have a comma before the "and". This is because the center section is a clause and as such should be formatted in such a way that if you take out the section inside the comments, the outside sentence still makes sense on it's own. For example:

> The child is only 4 years old and, despite this, they can already talk.
>   The child is only 4 years old and they can already talk.

The clause is used to add more detail to a specific part of the sentence, in this case, the fact that the child can talk.

Answer (score 1):

I would re-organize the sentences a bit and use "considering".

> **con·sid·er·ing**
>   preposition
>   1.
>   taking into account; in view of: The campaign was a great success, considering the strong opposition.

Thus,

> Considering the child is only 4 years old, it can already talk.